# Include without pagebreak

Tags: page-breaking, include

I really like the `\input` command, but what I really like more is the `\includeonly` command.
Is there a way to have the best of these worlds? (i.e. an `\inputonly` or an `\include` without page-breaks?)

Comment: The way that `\include` works is tied very much to forcing a new page (to ensure that items go to the correct `.aux` file at shipout).

Answer (score 15):

You won't get the behaviour that `\include` gives, where it saves the missing page numbers, chapter/footnote/equation/theorem/etc counters, bibliographic citations, etc, but if all you want is the ability to conditionally select which pieces of the document you want to compile, then there are several options, as [discussed in the FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-conditional). The `comment`, `version`, `optional`, `versions` packages allow this.

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately what I'd really like is the behaviour of \include. Just like to avoid those nasty pagebreaks!

Comment: Which behavior of `\include` is it that you want?

Comment: I guess references are the thing I'd care most about. Of course counters would also be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is it even possible? That `\include` keeps tracks of counters and references is tied to the fact that it generates a separate `.aux` for each included file. Perhaps the easiest thing it to just modify your work flow: forget about page breaks in the drafting stage and use `\include` and once the content is set, recompile using `\input`?

Comment: @Willie: That is my current strategy. But since I was hanging around here I thought I might ask for a different solution.

Answer (score 12):

If your really want to suppress the page break, which is caused by a `\clearpage` at the end of `\include`, then your can temporarily redefine this macro.

The `filehook` package can be used for this:

```
\usepackage{filehook}
\AtEndOfIncludes{%
  \global\let\savedclearpage\clearpage
  \global\let\clearpage\relax
}
\AfterIncludes{%
  \global\let\clearpage\savedclearpage
}
```

I'm not sure right now if `\global` is required here but it will not hurt.

As already mentioned it is **not guaranteed** anymore that `\includeonly` gives correct results, e.g. page numbers, because the last page wasn't flushed.

---

If you only want to suppress certain input files, then you need a `\inputonly` macro:

```
% You can put this into a `.sty` file and load it with `\usepackage{ }`
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\inputonly}[1]{\gdef\@inputonly{,#1,}}
\@onlypreamble\inputonly % Make it only valid in the preamble 
\newcommand*{\oinput}[1]{%
   \begingroup
   \edef\@tempa{{,#1,}{\@inputonly}}%
   \expandafter\in@\@tempa
   \ifin@
     \endgroup
     \input{#1}%
     % Dump counter values here
   \else
     \endgroup
     % maybe add a \message{ } here
     % Load counter values here
     \expandafter\ignorespaces
   \fi
}
```

Usage:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Insert or load above code

% Use `\oinput` instead of `\input`:
\inputonly{aa,bb,cc}
\begin{document}
\oinput{aa}
\oinput{bb}
\oinput{ccc}% will not be `\input`ed
\oinput{cc}
\end{document}
```

The `\input` macro is also used by packages to read a lot of other files, so it cannot safely be overwritten. A different name, e.g. `\oinput`, must be used instead.

If you want to keep counter values you have to dump and load them by yourself. See the code of `\include` how it is done.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\inputonly#1{\inputonly@i#1,,\@nil}
\def\inputonly@i#1,#2,#3\@nil{%
  \global\@namedef{#1input}{#1}
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\inputonly@i#2,#3\@nil\fi}
\def\Input#1{\expandafter\ifx\csname#1input\endcsname\relax\else\input{#1}\fi}
\makeatother
\inputonly{aa,bb,cc}

\begin{document}
\Input{aa}
\Input{bb}
\Input{ccc}% will not be read
\Input{cc}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have understand what you need. If you don't like the bothersome pagebreaks at the end of your chapters, you should use "openany" like following:

```
‎\documentclass[openany]{book}‎
```

Comment: The `openany` class option does not prevent page breaks before chapters - it only allows that new chapters start on left-hand (even) pages.