# Page break with \include

Tags: page-breaking, include

I like to print my drafts with big fonts and small margins (i do this in memoir style in a single chapter), but the `\include` comand creates a page break. Is there a way to avoid this and have section after section continuously?

Comment: You could use `\input` instead of `\include`.

Comment: Indeed. See [When should I use \input vs \include ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) for more details.

Comment: The question doesn't actually have anything to do with memoir; please change the title to something indicative of the actual contents.

Comment: Could the forced page break be removed by `\cleardoublepage`?

Comment: @Harrold: No, `\include` uses `\clearpage` at the beginning. This is by design. If you don't want a page break don't use `\include`. See also the discussion in [Include without pagebreak](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2334/include-without-pagebreak).

Comment: @Martin: I understand, thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It seems that you have your sections in extra files. First of all, this is not required by (La)TeX, you can have it all in one file if you want. (I imagine some people just get this taught from a template).

The `\include` command adds the page break by design and is intended for chapters which will start a new page anyway. The page break is required to make `\includeonly` work properly, e.g. insert the correct page numbers after any skipped chapter. If you simply want to insert your external files use the `\input` macro instead. It does not add a line break. See [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) for a description of the differences between these two macros.

However, if you want to still use `\includeonly` you are in trouble. In this case, see the question [Include without pagebreak](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2334/include-without-pagebreak) and its proposed solutions.