# \include puts everything on a new page

Tags: page-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Page break with \include](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18110/page-break-with-include)

I have got my LaTeX documents split in to several files, but when I input them in to my main document it starts the content on a new page. How can I stop this from happening?
Here is what's going on:
[image: outputFromLatex]

In my separate files I start each with:

```
\subsubsection{Sub-Sub-Section Title}
```

And in my main document i'm inputting the files by saying:

```
\include{resonantCircuits}
```

Is there anyway I can get it to continue on the same page instead of having this page break?

Comment: The title says `\input`, but the question body says `\include`?

Comment: Sorry I was originally using \input then tried \include and I had just copied and pasted from my document. I have changed it now.

Comment: And it typesets correctly. This question is redundant now.

Comment: On an un-related note, a lot of folks put Table captions *above* the table, and avoid vertical lines. Have a look at the `booktabs` documentation for more details

Comment: I have changed the question so that it states `\include` instead of `\input`. Otherwise it won't make any sense. I did this because future visitors to this question (with a similar problem) won't understand it otherwise.

Comment: Have also a look at [When should I use \input vs \include?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Use `\input` instead of `\include`.

Comment: Is there an equivalent of ```\includeonly``` for ```\input```?

Comment: I just switched from ```\input``` to ```\include``` in order to be able to remove all figures from a manuscript before compiling it via Pandoc to create a .docx without images in the text. Now some images appear like ```[!p]``` despite other options are set and it was not this way with ```\include```. However, I'd like the functionality of excluding them in the preamble...

Answer (score 3):

If you really want this, you can try with:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@include#1 {%
%  \clearpage % This was removed from latex.ltx definition
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\@input{#1.aux}}%
  \fi
  \@tempswatrue
  \if@partsw
    \@tempswafalse
    \edef\reserved@b{#1}%
    \@for\reserved@a:=\@partlist\do
      {\ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b\@tempswatrue\fi}%
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \let\@auxout\@partaux
    \if@filesw
      \immediate\openout\@partaux #1.aux
      \immediate\write\@partaux{\relax}%
    \fi
    \@input@{#1.tex}%
    \clearpage
    \@writeckpt{#1}%
    \if@filesw
      \immediate\closeout\@partaux
    \fi
  \else
    \deadcycles\z@
    \@nameuse{cp@#1}%
  \fi
  \let\@auxout\@mainaux}
\makeatother
```

However, this will cause problems because the page numbers will probably be wrong when `\includeonly`-ing some parts of the document.

I wouldn't do that, and stick to `\input`.

Comment: It is so ugly that it works 10 years later, copied from `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx`. Thank you @jean-christophe-dubacq!