# Blank page inserted when using \include

Tags: include

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Page break with \include](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18110/page-break-with-include)

I am using the Report document class and to manage the document i have divided it into seperate .tex files that are compiled within a main document. The main document contains the prefatory material and begins as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\includeonly{MF2_Formal_RPT_Cover&Title,CommonwealthDisclaimer,InstructionsForReaders,SignaturePage}
```

I then include the various report parts using:

```
\begin{document}
\include{MF2_Formal_RPT_Cover&Title}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Prefatory pages for the report %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\include{CommonwealthDisclaimer}
\include{InstructionsForReaders}
\include{SignaturePage}
\end{document}
```

When I compile the document a blank page is being inserted between each new included file. I have checked each file and they do not finish with a page break or similar. How can I stop the inclusion of the extra blank pages?

Comment: Please, show how the included files start.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4):

Use `\input` instead of `\include`.

Comment: because `\include` allways includes first a blank page, then print the text.  `\include` is very usefull to include chapters (beginning on a new page) in your document. `\input` does not insert a blank page.