# How to avoid page break when using \include?

Tags: page-breaking, include

I am writing a book, the format goes like this: Theory -> Answer key -> Hints -> Solutions. I have separate tex files for theory, answer key, hints and solutions. The problem is that when I combine all of them by using `\include`, I am getting automatic page break which I don't want. How can I avoid it?

I am attaching a screenshot for better understanding.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Use \input instead.

Comment: As mentioned use `\input` instead. `\include`'s support for `\includeonly ` needs the page break to function properly

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thanks! It is working, you can post this comment as an answer, I shall accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Page break with \include](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18110/page-break-with-include)

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include (the highest voted question on the  whole site:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **\input** instead since **\include** automatically inserts a page break.

I am currently on my phone and I have limited access to the internet. But I would be surprised if there in not already a similar question on this site :).