# Blank pages after \include in LaTeX report class

Tags: input, include, blank-page

I'm writing my thesis as several separate chapters and incorporating them into one `.tex` file.

Some of the chapters are pdfs of articles, and they are simply added to my `master.tex` using `\input`.

However, 2 chapters are 'traditionally' written (not published articles) and include a bibliography at the end of each chapter. For this reason, I use `chapterbib` with `[sectionbib]` enabled. And in order for the separate bibliographies to appear, I have to `\include` these chapters, rather than `\input`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in, left=1.57in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}

\input{frontpage}
\input{abstracts}
\input{declarationandcopyright}
\input{acknowledgementsanddedictation}
\include{chapter1}
\input{chapter2}
\input{chapter3}
\input{chapter4}
\include{chapter5}
\input{chapter6}

\end{document}
```

The problem: I'm getting two additional blank pages before the start of chapter 1, one extra blank page before the start of chapter 2, but no extra blank pages in between chapters 2-3 or 3-4 etc.

An example of one of my `\include` chapters:

```
\chapter{Introduction}

\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{lot}{chapter}{Introduction}
\section{A subtitle}
Some text here
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{library}
```

An example of one of my `\input` chapters:

```
\chapter{chapter3}
\includepdf[pages=-, scale=0.9, offset=30 1]{paper2.pdf}
```

I have to compile each `\include` chapter individually in BibTeX, then run PDFLaTeX twice on my `master.tex`.

I assumed it was a problem with LaTeX trying to keep the first page of each chapter on an odd numbered page. But actually it's putting them on odd or even. So perhaps it's something to do with the bibliographies?

Any suggestions about how I can get rid of all these blank pages? Much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Related: [When should I use `\input` vs. `\include`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/5764)

Comment: `\include` does a `\clearpage` before and after the content that is included; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include/250#250). If you need to use `\include` with no page breaks, then see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209065/to-have-no-pagebreak-after-include-in-latex/1210233#1210233).

Comment: Okay, my solution. Using \let\clearpage\relax does work (gets rid of blank space between chapters), however I have some landscape-orientated tables in my document, and they went horrible wrong when I did this. So I used the 'newclude' package (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/frankenstein) alongside \include*(mychapter) and it worked a treat.

Answer (score 10):

The following answer is basically a copy of [Will Robertson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/179/will-robertson)'s [answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209065/to-have-no-pagebreak-after-include-in-latex/1210233#1210233). It seems that it doesn't actually have an answer on TeX.SX, so I thought that I would post it here, too.

`\include` issues a `\clearpage` before and after the content that is included. There are two ways around this.

The first way is to use `\input` instead of `\include` (*cf.*, [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include/)).

However, since the OP is after a method that functions as `\include` does, the second option, then, is to utilize the package `newclude` which provides the command `\include*`. This command does **not** issue the `\clearpage` at the beginning and at the end of the `\include`d content.

---

See also:

- [Page break with \include](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18110/page-break-with-include)
- [Include without pagebreak](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2334/include-without-pagebreak)

(Though none of the answers to these questions mention [the answer provided by Will Robertson on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209065/to-have-no-pagebreak-after-include-in-latex/1210233#1210233).)

Answer (score 1):

A simpler, and in my experience, more robust solution:

```
\let\oldInclude=\include
\def\include#1{\bgroup\def\clearpage{\relax}\oldInclude{#1}\egroup}
```

Comment: I know this thread is like, a million years old, but I'm up-voting your solution. This is the perfect mix of familiar (because no new packages), succinct, and robust. Many thanks for this! **Update:** I just discovered that this solution breaks the use of `\usepackage{xr}` to cross-list Theorems/Lemmas/etc. with the same name (in different files) from one file to the other. I'm going to tinker to try to rectify but for most cases, I think it's safe to say that your solution will be a non-issue.

Comment: the `\clearpage` in `\include` in necessary, this completely breaks `\include` functionality.  Use `\input` if you do not want `\include`.