# includeonly and page numbering

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, include

I am writing a fairly large documents that contains different chapters included in the main .tex file using the `\include` command. I find this to be practical as I can then compile a single chapter keeping page numbers and links to other chapters using the `\includeonly` command.

Recently, I found that `\inlcudeonly` may be responsible for the addition of a blank page at the end of a document though. I found [a fix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129065/blank-pages-after-include-in-latex-report-class) which is based on a redefinition of the `\include` command:

```
\let\oldInclude=\include
\def\include#1{\bgroup\def\clearpage{\relax}\oldInclude{#1}\egroup}
```

However, this fix seems to create some other issues. In my case, it impacts page numbering **due to a conflict with the hyperref package**. Everything is fine when compiling the whole document but the compilation of a single chapter (or more) using `\includeonly` yields some wrong numbering of the last two pages...

I was able to reduce the problem to a mwe where the application of this fix generates a compilation issue. Here are the commands to execute to see the problem: `pdflatex main.tex`. The compiled pdf has then proper page numbering. Then uncomment the line of `\includeonly` and run: `pdflatex main.tex` again.

The resulting pdf has **unproper page numbering**...

with **main.tex**:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,fleq,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

% fix
\let\oldInclude=\include
\def\include#1{\bgroup\def\clearpage{\relax}\oldInclude{#1}\egroup}

%\includeonly{chapitre_1}

\begin{document}
    \include{description}
    \include{chapitre_1}
    \include{chapitre_1_exercices}
\end{document}
```

and where **description.tex** is:

```
\newpage
\section*{Plan de cours pour la session d'}
Le cours \dots
```

**chapitre_1.tex** is:

```
\newpage
\section{Chapitre 1}

\label{chap_1}
% table des matières
\newpage
\subsection{Introduction}
    Contenu du chapitre\dots
\newpage
    page supplémentaire pour afficher les numéros de page
```

and **chapitre_1_exercices.tex** is:

```
\newpage        
\subsection{Exercices d'application}
    Liste d'exercices\dots
```

I do not see how to update the fix...

Comment: I don't know where this idea to redefine `\clearpage` comes from it has appeared here a few times recently. redefining `\clearpage` in that way completely breaks latex, the simple answer is do not do that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see... But do you see any alternative to the issue for which this "fix" was initially proposed ? Without this redefinition, there can be extra blank pages at the end of the compiled pdf.

Comment: an extra `\clearpage` (from `\include` or anything else) just before `\end{document}` shouldn't make a blank page, if you have an example of that post an example in a question and will try to debug.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you, I created a post on this other issue here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427197/blank-page-after-includeonly